24.04.1 fresh install can't resolve .local servers
I installed from ubuntu-24.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso downloaded Dec. 23,2024.
This is the headless server. The install went with no issues. I'm using a wired internet connection.
The server shows up on my router.
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade ran without issues.
I can ssh into the server using it's ip address. When I run
ping server2.local
I get
ping: server2.local: Temporary failure in name resolution
